# How can I make the ball bounce off the red bricks without it (the red brick) breaking?

Tags: javascript, canvas

So basically I want the red bricks to have an extra bounce (but not the blue ones). It means if I hit it once the red brick reflects the ball without it disappearing but when I hit it the second time it does. Thank you in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Breakout_Game</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

        <script type="text/javascript">
   
            var canvas, canvasContext;
            var ballX = 75, ballY = 75;
            var ballSpeedX = 3, ballSpeedY = 3;
            var ballR = 7;

            const brickW = 80;
            const brickH = 20;
            const brickCols = Math.floor(800 / brickW);
            const brickRows = Math.floor(600 / (brickH * 3));
            const brickGap = 1;

            var brickGrid = new Array(brickCols * brickRows);
            var bricksLeft = 0;

            const paddleW = 100, paddleH = 10;
            var paddleX = 400, paddleY = 600;
            const distanceBP = 60;

            var mouseX, mouseY;

            function updateMousePos (evt) {
  
                var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); // this is for adjustments only (getting the mouse coordinates even if the page is scrollable)
                var root = document.documentElement;

                mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft; // clientX is the X of mouse
                mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;

                paddleX = mouseX - paddleW/2;
                /* //Cheats Help debugging
                ballX = mouseX;
                ballY = mouseY;*/

            }

            function brickReset () {
                bricksLeft = 0;
                var i;
                for(i = 0; i < 3 * brickCols; i++) {
                    brickGrid[i] = false;
                }
                for (; i < brickCols * brickRows; i++) {
                    brickGrid[i] = true;
                    bricksLeft++;
                }
                randBrickColor();

            }

            window.onload = function () {

                canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

                var fps = 60;
                setInterval(updateAll, 1000 / fps);

                canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", updateMousePos); // everytime the mouse moves we call the function updateMousePos()
                brickReset();
                ballReset();

            }

            function updateAll () {
                drawAll();
                moveAll();
            }

            function ballReset () {
                ballX = canvas.width / 2;
                ballY = canvas.height / 2;
            }

            function ballMove () {
                ballX += ballSpeedX;
                ballY += ballSpeedY;
                //COLLISION

                //left
                if (ballX - ballR < 0 && ballSpeedX < 0.0) {
                    ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
                }
                //right
                if (ballX + ballR > canvas.width && ballSpeedX > 0.0) {
                    ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
                }
                //top
                if (ballY - ballR < 0 && ballSpeedY < 0.0) {
                    ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
                }

                //bottom
                if (ballY > canvas.height) {
                    ballReset();
                    brickReset();
                }

            }

            function isBrickAtColRow (col, row) {

                if (col >= 0 && col < brickCols && row >= 0 && row < brickRows) {
                    var brickIndexUnderCoord = rowColToArrayIndex(col, row);
                    return brickGrid[brickIndexUnderCoord];
                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            }

            function ballBrickHandling () {

                var ballBrickCol = Math.floor(ballX  / brickW);
                var ballBrickRow = Math.floor(ballY / brickH);
                var brickIndexUnderBall = rowColToArrayIndex(ballBrickCol, ballBrickRow);

                if (brickIndexUnderBall >= 0 && brickIndexUnderBall < brickCols * brickRows) {

                    if (isBrickAtColRow( ballBrickCol,ballBrickRow)) {
                        brickGrid[brickIndexUnderBall] = false;
                        bricksLeft--;
                        //console.log( bricksLeft)

                        var prevBallX = ballX - ballSpeedX;
                        var prevBallY = ballY - ballSpeedY;
                        var prevBrickCol = Math.floor(prevBallX / brickW);
                        var prevBrickRow = Math.floor(prevBallY / brickH);

                        var bothTestsFailed = true;

                        if (prevBrickCol != ballBrickCol) {

                            if (isBrickAtColRow(prevBrickCol, ballBrickRow) == false) {
                                ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
                                bothTestsFailed = false;
                            }

                        }

                        if (prevBrickRow != ballBrickRow) {

                            if (isBrickAtColRow(ballBrickCol, prevBrickRow) == false) {
                                ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
                                bothTestsFailed = false;
                            }

                        }

                        if (bothTestsFailed) {
                            ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
                            ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            function ballPaddleHandling () {

                var paddleTopEdgeY = canvas.height - distanceBP;
                var paddleBottomEdgeY = paddleTopEdgeY + paddleH;
                var paddleLeftEdgeX = paddleX;
                var paddleRightEdgeX = paddleLeftEdgeX + paddleW;

                if (ballY + ballR > paddleTopEdgeY &&
                    ballY - ballR < paddleBottomEdgeY &&
                    ballX + ballR > paddleLeftEdgeX &&
                    ballX - ballR < paddleRightEdgeX
                ) {
                    ballSpeedY *= -1;

                    var centerOfPaddleX = paddleX + paddleW / 2;
                    var ballDistFromPadlleCenterX = ballX - centerOfPaddleX;
                    ballSpeedX = ballDistFromPadlleCenterX * 0.2;

                    if (bricksLeft == 0) {
                        brickReset();
                    }

                }

            }

            function moveAll () {

                //console.log("X: " + ballSpeedX,"Y: " + ballSpeedY);
         
                ballMove();
                ballBrickHandling();
                ballPaddleHandling();

            }

            function rowColToArrayIndex (col, row) {
                return col + brickCols * row;
            }

            // Random COLOR
            var brickColors = [];

            function randBrickColor () {

                for (var eachRow = 0; eachRow < brickRows; eachRow++) {

                    brickColors[eachRow] = [];

                    for (var eachCol = 0; eachCol < brickCols; eachCol++) {

                         if (Math.random() > 0.7) {
                             brickColors[eachRow][eachCol] = "red";
                         } else {
                             brickColors[eachRow][eachCol] = "blue";
                         }

                     }

                 }

             }
             //end of Random COLOR

             function drawBricks () {

                 for (var eachRow = 0; eachRow < brickRows; eachRow++) {

                     for (var eachCol = 0; eachCol < brickCols; eachCol++) {

                         var arrayIndex = brickCols * eachRow + eachCol;

                         if (brickGrid[arrayIndex]) {
                             colorRect(brickW * eachCol, brickH * eachRow, brickW-brickGap, brickH-brickGap, brickColors[eachRow][eachCol]);
                         }

                     }

                 }

             }

             function drawAll () {

                 // Black Screen
                 colorRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height, "black");
                 // Ball
                 colorCircle(ballX,ballY, ballR, "white");
                 // Paddle
                 colorRect(paddleX, paddleY - distanceBP, paddleW, paddleH, "white");
                 // Bricks
                 drawBricks();
                 // Position of the mouse
                 colorText(mouseX+","+mouseY, mouseX,mouseY, "yellow");

             }

             function colorRect (topLeftX, topLeftY, boxWidth, boxHeight, fillColor) {

                 canvasContext.fillStyle = fillColor;
                 canvasContext.fillRect(topLeftX, topLeftY, boxWidth, boxHeight);

             }

             function colorCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, fillColor) {
                 canvasContext.fillStyle = fillColor;
                 canvasContext.beginPath();
                 canvasContext.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                 canvasContext.fill();
             }

             function colorText(showWords, textX, textY, fillColor) {
                 canvasContext.fillStyle = fillColor;
                 canvasContext.fillText(showWords, textX, textY);
             }

         </script>

     </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you getting an error? Tell us exactly what issue you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `ballBrickHandling()` replace

```
brickGrid[brickIndexUnderBall] = false;
bricksLeft--;
```

with

```
if(brickColors[ballBrickRow][ballBrickCol] != "red") {
    brickGrid[brickIndexUnderBall] = false;
    bricksLeft--;
} else brickColors[ballBrickRow][ballBrickCol] = "blue"
```

Comment: this only make the red bricks stay after I hit them. What I want is that I have to  hit it twice to make it (the red brick) disapear.

Comment: @MohamedDouzi I had made an update, it should make them blue now. So they are red, you hit. They go blue and you hit them again remove them.

Comment: thanks .. exactly what I've been looking to do :)